# How to detect an app displays an image in android

Tags: android

By using

```
List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > runningTaskInfo = manager.getRunningTasks(1);
```

We can get the list of currently open apps in an android device.

But Is there any method or idea to detect an app displays an image in foreground in android?

Comment: "We can get the list of currently open apps in an android device" -- not on Android 5.0+. "Is there any method or idea to detect an app displays an image in foreground in android?" -- apps almost always display an image in the foreground.

Comment: apps almost always display an image in the foreground.....??? Anyway I need to detect whether an image is displayed in the forground or not. if displayed my app must trigger some event....

Comment: "apps almost always display an image in the foreground.....?" -- sure. Many widgets involve some sort of an image as part of their rendering, such as `ImageView`, `Button`, `ImageButton`, `EditText`, `Spinner`, `CheckBox`, `ToggleButton`, `Switch`, etc. Plus, there are images used for action bar items, the "hamburger" toggle, and the "up" affordance in the action bar. I do not know what you consider "an image is displayed in the foreground" to mean, but computer programmers would consider any of the above things to qualify.

Comment: I want my app to trigger some events when users click on any photos in whatsapp, facebook, gallery or any other apps. Can you help me on this?

Comment: You have no simple means of knowing if another app is even showing a photo, let alone if the user clicks on one.